# How to pass a optional parameter into ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This works:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, CompPhone cmpPhn)
{
  var vM = new MyViewModel();
  if (cmpPhn != null) { vM.CmpPhnF = cmpPhn; }
  ...
}
```

If I make cmpPhn optional:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, CompPhone? cmpPhn)
```

I get "Error 1 The type 'MyProject.Models.CompPhone' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'.

How can I make this input parameter to the method optional?

Here's the view model

```
public class MyViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
...
public CompPhone CmpPhnF { get; set; }    
...
}
```

Calling method

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult PhoneTest(MyViewModel vM)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  { var cmpPhn = vM.CmpPhnF;
  return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = vM.AcntId, cmpPhn });
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not making it optional, you are making it `nullable`. To make it optional you need to define a default value for the parameter. (Its only available for C# 4.0 or above):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, CompPhone cmpPhn = null)
```

your current code is specifying to be `Nullable` and it seems that `CompPhone` **is a class not a value type**, and can't be `Nullable`.

`CompPhone? cmpPhn` is equivalent to `Nullable<CompPhone>` where `CompPhone` should be a `struct`

Comment: Thanks Habib for clearing that subtlety between nullable and optional up. I prefer your answer over rablinz's since it doesn't require duplicating the method. And yes CompPhone is a class.

Comment: @Joe, rablinz's answer is also valid, but if you are using .Net framework 4.0 or above then it comes with C# 4.0 which has the default parameter option for a method. Prior to that version, you have to adapt to rablinz's answer

Comment: I've added the calling method to my question.  You answered how to take the class into a method.  I have a follow up question of how to pass a class out of a method.  When I debug the calling method the id but not the cmpPhn gets added to the route values.  Thanks

Comment: thanks to @Joe for asking this by using nullable and for you Habib to point out the difference, I confused the two for the same until encountered this post, lucky day for me!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Habib, you are making the parameter `nullable`.

To make the parameter optional define two identical methods, one with the parameter and one without. The one without will have to use a predefined default value for it.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var vM = new MyViewModel();
  vM.CmpPhnF = defaultValue;
  ...
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, CompPhone cmpPhn)
{
  var vM = new MyViewModel();
  if (cmpPhn != null) { vM.CmpPhnF = cmpPhn; }
  ...
}
```